# What is the term for someone who unnecessarily defends someone else?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I got a conversation with my husband about noticing more and more that people seem to be butting in and trying to defend people who don’t need defending: people getting angry over situations that they have nothing to do with them, trying to intervene in the situation when nobody else is angry about the situation including the person that they feel needs to be defended.

Comment: Kind? Altruistic? Saintly? Nosy? Busybody? Neighborly? Fighting for the underdog but misinformed? Mansplaining male chauvinist? Playing mayor? Zorro? The Lone Ranger? Tom Joad of The Grapes of Wrath?

Comment: Serial unsolicited advocate

Comment: Injustice collector?

Comment: White knighting. Especially when trying to defend someone against some discrimination when no discrimination happened.

Comment: I think white knight is the closest one I've seen. But of course most people won't know it has a different meaning. Then the typical white knight meaning. Definitely the slang but it fits perfectly

Comment: [to have a conversation, not get one; get into a conversation, yes]

Comment: White knighting normally refers to men defending women, so it won't apply to all cases.

Comment: I suggest there is no such term.

If you insist there is, can you Post any useful clues?